# Simplify Ruby conditional involving regex and two vars?

Tags: ruby, regex, conditional-statements

The goal is to Rubify (ie. use some Ruby magic) the so commented code.

I'm learning Ruby and it seems every time I write a bit of code, Ruby has some magic that can simplify and make it more readable.

For example (and unrelated to the code below), instead of writing a loop to iterate over an array of integers to get the sum, in Ruby, `sum = array.inject(:+)` works magic.

```
string = 'abcd'
inn = ''
out = ''
letters = 'az'

# Rubify below, por favor
letters.split('').each do |l|
  if string[/#{l}/i]
    inn << l
  else
    out << l
  end
end
```

Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by rubify? That seems to be in Ruby already :-P

Comment: @DJ. I updated the question to clear it up ... with hope.

Comment: Something like this:

`irb(main):005:0> inn = string.chars.select { |c| letters.chars.include?(c) }
=> ["a"]
`?

Comment: `inn = string.scan(/[#{letters}]/).join`

Comment: We applaud your enthusiasm for Ruby, but it does not belong in your SO questions. Here, for example, your second and third paragraphs are irrelevant and therefore should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = 'abcd'
letters = 'az'
inn, out = letters.chars.partition{|char| string.include?(char)}.map!(&:join)
```